# PHP - POST to Class not working

Tags: php

I have a form that I'd like to post to a class but whenever, I click on Submit, the console returns a `GET` instead of `POST` with all my field name and value in the URL like this `http://rogerstracker.com/2/priority.php?yourName=&functionalArea=&publicationWeek=&otherCommunication=&LifeCycles%5B%5D=&priorityTitle=&IQLink=&IQliveDate=&nameOfKMSpecialist=&consideredPriority=&Content=&priorityRequest=Priority+Request&emp_id=&postPriorityRequest=Submit`

Here's my class

```
class Post_Form
{

    private $db_connection              = null;
    private $lang                       = array();
    public  $errors                     = array();
    public  $messages                   = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->lang = & $GLOBALS['_language'];

        // if a POST request exist, call the insertNewPriorityRequest()

        if (isset($_POST["postPriorityRequest"])) {
            $this->insertNewPriorityRequest(currentDateTime(), $_POST["priorityRequest"], $_POST["yourName"], $_POST["emp_id"], $_POST["functionalArea"], $_POST["publicationWeek"], $_POST["otherCommunication"], $_POST["allAudiences"], $_POST["LifeCycles[]"], $_POST["priorityTitle"], $_POST["IQLink"], $_POST["IQliveDate"], $_POST["nameOfKMSpecialist"], $_POST["consideredPriority"], $_POST["Content"]);
        }
    }

    // Checks if database connection
    private function databaseConnection()
    {
        // connection already opened
        if ($this->db_connection != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            // create a database connection, using the constants from config/config.php
            try {
                $this->db_connection = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
                return true;
            // If an error is catched, database connection failed
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                $this->errors[] = $this->lang['Database error'];
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Handles form posting process. Return possible errors, and insert new ticket in the database
    private function insertNewPriorityRequest($currentDateTime, $priorityRequest, $yourName, $emp_id, $functionalArea, $publicationWeek, $otherCommunication, $allAudiences, $LifeCycles, $priorityTitle, $IQLink, $IQliveDate, $nameOfKMSpecialist, $consideredPriority, $Content)
    {
        // Check which life cycles are selected
        if (isset($allAudiences)) {
            $audiance = $allAudiences.implode(', ', $LifeCycles);
        } else {
            $audiance = implode(', ', $LifeCycles);
        }

        // Validate data
        if (strlen($Content) > 300 || strlen($Content) < 1) {
            $this->errors[] = $this->lang['Content too long'];
        // If the above checks are okay
        } else if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
            // Write new ticket
            $insert_ticket = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO ccc_tickets (EMP_ID, `date`, submitter, priority, assigned, type) VALUES (:emp_id, :currentdate, :yourName, :priority, :assigned, :type);');
            $insert_ticket->bindValue(':emp_id', $emp_id);
            $insert_ticket->bindValue(':currentdate', $currentDateTime);
            $insert_ticket->bindValue(':yourName', $yourName);
            $insert_ticket->bindValue(':priority', $priority);
            $insert_ticket->bindValue(':assigned', $assignedTo);
            $insert_ticket->bindValue(':type', $priorityRequest);
            $insert_ticket->execute();

            // Return id of new ticket id
            $ticket_results = $this->db_connection->lastInsertId();

            // Write new priority request into database
            $insert_priority_request = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO ccc_priority_request (ticket_id, functionalArea, publicationWeek, otherCommunication, lifeCycles, priorityTitle, IQLink, IQliveDate, nameOfKMSpecialist, consideredPriority, Content) VALUES (:ticket_id, :functionalArea, :publicationWeek, :otherCommunication, :allAudiences, :LifeCycles, :priorityTitle, :IQLink, :IQliveDate, :nameOfKMSpecialist, :consideredPriority, :Content);');
            $insert_priority_request->bindValue(':ticket_id', $ticket_results);
            $insert_priority_request->bindValue(':functionalArea', $functionalArea);
            $insert_priority_request->bindValue(':publicationWeek', $publicationWeek);
            $insert_priority_request->bindValue(':otherCommunication', $otherCommunication);
            $insert_priority_request->bindValue(':LifeCycles', $LifeCycles);
            $insert_priority_request->bindValue(':priorityTitle', $priorityTitle);
            $insert_priority_request->bindValue(':IQLink', $IQLink);
            $insert_priority_request->bindValue(':IQliveDate', $IQliveDate);
            $insert_priority_request->bindValue(':nameOfKMSpecialist', $nameOfKMSpecialist);
            $insert_priority_request->bindValue(':consideredPriority', $consideredPriority);
            $insert_priority_request->bindValue(':Content', $Content);
            $insert_priority_request->execute();

            // Return messages
            if ($insert_priority_request) {
                $this->messages[] = $this->lang['Success'];
                $this->post_successful = true;
            } else {
                $this->errors[] = $this->lang['Error'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `priority.php` calling the `Post_Form` Calss

`$submit_post_form = new Post_Form();`

Here's my HTML mark up:

```
<form action="priority.php" type="POST" name="priorityRequestForm">
    [ . . . ] <!-- The form is too long and they're just input text fields -->
    <input type="submit" name="postPriorityRequest" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense: `& $GLOBALS['_language'];`

Comment: How so? Can you please elaborate? The full code should be `$_language = array('Error' => 'An error has occured.',
'Success' => 'Your form has been successfully submitted.');`

Comment: Why do you use the `&` sign?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be `method="POST"`, not `type=`.

Comment: Oh wow! I can't believe I didn't see it. I guess I must be really tired haha!